# Reading values from ajax return in json format

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

In ajax return, i am getting json as

```
[{"colourname":"red,yellow"}]
```

i want to fetch `"red,yellow"` string from json ,

ajax call se ,

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "loadData.php",
    data: {
        productid: 'getId'
    }
}).done(function (msg) {
    alert('get ' + msg);
});
```

I tried ,

```
msg[0].colourname  
msg["colourname"]
```

Nothing worked how can i access values?

Answer (score 6):

The response returned by `$.ajax` in `done` is a raw string, not a JavaScript object. Set `dataType: 'json'` in the ajax configuration and `jQuery` will parse the JSON `msg` as a JavaScript object.

```
$.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : "loadData.php",
        data : {
        productid : 'getId'
        },
        dataType: 'json', 
}).done(function(msg) {
     alert('get '+msg);
});
```

Setting the `dataType` explicitly is not required if you send the server response with `Content-Type: application/json`

BTW, you should use an array for `colourNames`: `{"colournames":["red","yellow"] }`

Comment: Or (preferably, if you control the server) have the correct `Content-Type` header on the response.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "loadData.php",
    dataType: 'json'
    data: {
        productid: 'getId'
    }
}).done(function (msg) {
    alert('get ' + msg);
});
});
```