# Accessing PHP array value in jQuery.ajax is not working

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, json, ajax

I am using `jQuery.ajax` to send user input to PHP and get an array back. While I alert/console.log the response, it perfectly shows the array in the alert. But while trying to access an individual element of the array, I am getting `undefined` error. I need to access individual element of the array. What am I doing wrong? Please help.

**instagram.php**

```
$nola = array("mediac" => $bola, "userc" => $bola2);
echo json_encode($nola);
```

**jquery ajax file**

```
var formData = jQuery('#myForminstagram').serialize();
jQuery.ajax({
        url:'instagram.php',
        type:'POST',
        data: formData,
        success: function(response) {
                var myuser = response.userc;
                alert(response); //works & shows the array as {"mediac" => $bola, "userc" => $bola2}
                alert(myuser); // doesn't work & show undefined error
                }
    });
```

Comment: Seems like you get the json serialized. Try adding the property `dataType: 'json'` to your Ajax request to make jQuery parse the result as json automatically. You should also use `console.log()` instead of `alert()` since the later won't be able to output arrays or objects.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reading values from ajax return in json format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19900504/reading-values-from-ajax-return-in-json-format)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because your jquery code read the response as text, not json, so you have to tell it to read as json, by doing this:

1.You can add `header('Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8');` to your instagram.php.

Or

2.You can add `dataType: 'json'` to your jquery ajax file.